# как в rails обращаться к массиву из базы данных в модели?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

У меня есть модель с полем в бд, в которое кладется массив со списком методов. Массив `testcase` генерируется в форме

```
<%= simple_form_for @testrun do |f| %>

<%= f.input :testcase, as: :check_boxes,
      collection: [["test1", :test1], ["test2", :test2]] %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

в контреллере в методе `create` создается джоба в `sidekiq`

```
  def create
    @testrun = Testrun.new(testrun_params)

    if @testrun.save
      Testrun.delay.process!(@testrun.id)
      redirect_to @testrun, notice: 'Test run was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

в модели метод `process!` выглядит так

```
def process!
    self.log ||= ''
    running!
    save!
    @test = Case.new(self)
    @testrun[:testcase].each do |testcase|
      @test.send testcase
    end
    completed!
    save!
  end
```

в классе `Case` содержатся методы из массива `testcase`. В итоге нужно, чтобы после создания testrun прогонялись все методы из массива testcase. Но на деле sidekiq выдает ошибку `"error_message":"undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass","error_class":"NoMethodError"`. Как правильно обращаться к этому массиву, чтобы вызвать методы в нем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите, в контроллере вы создали переменную `@testrun` - это инстанс-переменная, доступ к ней есть только в соответствующей вьюхе, а вот модель о ней не знает совершенно ничего. Вы же передаёте айдишник при выполнении `process!`, просто найдите по нему сущность:

```
def process!(id)
  self.log ||= ''
  running!
  save!
  test = Case.new(self) # полагаю, тут вам тоже хватит обычной переменной
  testrun = Testrun.find(id)
  testrun[:testcase].each do |testcase|
    test.send testcase
  end
  completed!
  save!
end
```

Comment: Спасибо, @Василиса. Я в общем-то уже решил это слегка иначе, но вероятнее всего Ваш вариант более подходящий.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту проблему таким способом.

```
testcases = Testrun.last[:testcase].reject(&:empty?)
testcases.each do |testcase|
  @test.send testcase
end
```

Не совсем уверен, что правильно(в глобальном смысле) брать последнюю запись в БД, но мою задачу это вроде бы неплохо решило